# How to load headers and footers present in .rtf file using c#?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I load a .rtf file into my text editor using richtextbox.loadfile(filepath,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
but its not loading the headers and footers present in the .rtf file and also i cant create a header and footer statically because the data in header is changing for every other .rtf files so, how can i load a .rtf file with headers and footers

Comment: Will that be for display only or also to modify and save? [Specs](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading29)

Comment: Only to display

Comment: It should be noted that every section in a document can have its own header&footer. By modifying the rtf code it ought to be possible to insert the header/footer data as plain text; the various destinations may be an issue. A header or footer can be displayed on all pages or all left/right pages etc.. To get this to display right one would need to scan the text for page breaks and maybe also for overflowing pages. Quite an order. Maybe two separate RTBs for header and footer are simpler that messing with the rtf itself. You would parse out the header and dump its text inot the RTB..

Comment: Looking a bit deeper I guess a) it is not easy to work out a general solution and b) the RTB has not concept of pages, so it can't handle headers/footers, which always rely on page breaks..

Comment: Ya, so that I installed devExpress trail version. By using rich text control , it is now loading the file including headers . But still didn't get how to load in richTextBox

Answer (score 0):

- The bad news is that is isn't really possible.

`RichTextBox` has no concept of pages; but **headers and footers rely on pages**.

Looking at the [rtff specs](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) we find: They can be on..

- every page
- every left or right page
- or only on the first page.

But without pages, displaying any of these eight types makes no sense.

- The good news is that it isn't terribly hard to strip out the headers and footers and put each in a separate rtb.

Let's start by looking at the `Rtf`; here we see that the rtb has already stripped out all things it doesn't need for what it actually can display. So the rtf of the headers and footers insn't even there anymore.

Instead we load the raw data directly from the file:

```
string rawRtf = File.ReadAllText(rtfPath);
```

Next we parse the curlies. Much simpler than expected; I use a `TreeView` to show them but any tree-node structure will do..:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
TreeNode cn = new TreeNode("rtf tree"); // a root node
cn = cn.Nodes.Add("");                  // first node
for (int i = 1; i < rawRtf.Length; i++)
{
    char p = rawRtf.Text[i - 1];
    char c = rawRtf.Text[i];

    // always watch for escaped curlies (but ignoring escaped blackslashes)
    // either closing or opening else real character:
    if (c=='}' && p != '\\') cn = cn.Parent;
    else if (c== '{' && p != '\\') cn = cn.Nodes.Add("");
    else cn.Text += c;
}
 treeView1.Nodes.Add(cn);
```

Let's have a look at the result:

[image]

The loaded document has a header and a footer with real text; both have an embedded set of curlies. There are also headers and footer with only a linefeed in them; we'll ignore those.

Now we want to pick all our results from the tree. We reassemble all header/footer nodes, restoring the curlies. For this we use a function to recursively collect them all.

We look for these [control words](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading29) at the beginning of node texts:

```
List<string> hdrftrWords = new List<string>(){
                @"\header ", @"\headerl", @"\headerr", @"\headerf",
                @"\footer ", @"\footerl", @"\footerr", @"\footerf"  };
```

To collect them is simple:

```
List<Tuple<string, TreeNode>>  hdrftrRtf = new List<Tuple<string, TreeNode>> ();

foreach (var hf in hdrftrWords)
{
    TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    // there may be more, but we'll only use the 1st..
    List<TreeNode> h1 = new List<TreeNode>();
    h1 = FindNodesByString(node, hf, h1);
    if (h1.Count > 0) hdrftrRtf.Add(new Tuple<string, TreeNode>(hf, h1[0]));
}
```

Here we have used a small recursive function to find nodes starting with a string:

```
List<TreeNode> FindNodesByString(TreeNode tn , string text, List<TreeNode> hits)
{
    if (tn.Text.StartsWith(text)) hits.Add(tn);
    foreach (TreeNode n in tn.Nodes) FindNodesByString(n, text, hits);
    return hits;
}
```

This is really all we need to strip out the headers and footers.

The resulting list has the rtf control words in `Item1` and the nodes in `Item2`.

To display them in `RichTextBoxes` is the trickiest part..:

```
foreach (var rtf in hdrftrRtf)
{
    var rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.SelectedText = "";
    int i = rtb.Rtf.Length - 9;
    string r = "";
    r = JoinNodeTexts(rtf.Item2, "{", "}", ref r);
    r = r.Replace(rtf.Item1, "");
    rtb.Rtf = rtb.Rtf.Insert(i, r);
    rtb.Width = flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Width - 10;
    if (rtb.Text.Trim().Length > 0) flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rtb);
}
```

Here is a function to join all node texts..:

```
string JoinNodeTexts(TreeNode tn, string prefix, string postfix, ref string joined)
{
    joined += prefix + tn.Text + postfix;
    foreach (TreeNode n in tn.Nodes) JoinNodeTexts(n, prefix, postfix, ref joined);
    return joined;
}
```

We remove the control word as we don't want to make the rtb think it has to deal with headers or footers after all. I also skip empty header/footer entries. ( The `\par`gets trimmmed away..)

After creating a rtb control, we trick it into working by adding an empty string; then we insert the raw headers and footers at the end minus a magic number which skips over the normal ending, i.e. over a line break, a closing curly, and then some..

The result is added to a `FlowLayoutPanel` for testing. Feel free to simply copy the `Text` and paste it to the start or end of your actual RTB..

[image]

Since I cheated with a basically empty rtb we are missing the original font- and color-tables at the top of the tree. If the headers/footers should display these as well one would have to parse out these tables from the tree as well..